# can't download the route-me code from svn

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, route-me

i try to follow [this article](http://www.gisnotes.com/wordpress/2009/12/iphone-dev-note-19-route-me-opensource-mapping-for-the-iphone/), the first step is to download the route-me code from svn:

```
svn co http://route-me.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ route-me
```

I really didn't understand how to follow up this instruction. I try to do it in the Terminal but seems not to be the good way.
How can i download that from svn?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your way, seems absolutely fine to me

Comment: I tried to check out this project with Tortoise SVN under Windows and I got no response from the server. But I think you can't use svn anymore, because it has been moved to git (According projects homepage).

Comment: @dimitrisli : what you mean it's fine, did you test it on the Terminal?

Comment: @reporter: i didn't understand you very well :)

Comment: @reporter: get it, seems the server not responding any more :)

Comment: I was beeing editing my comment, because I pressed the return key.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you visit the google code site: http://code.google.com/p/route-me/ You'll see that the project has been moved off of google code and onto github.

You can find the source and all branches here: https://github.com/route-me/route-me

If you don't have git for the command line, you can use the download button on the upper right to get the source code tarball or zip.

Second, the guide you're looking at is pretty old, its for ver 3.1.2 and xcode is currently ver 4.2.   For further help depending on your version of xcode  check out some guides here: https://github.com/route-me/route-me/wiki/Embedding-Guide and here: http://blueottersoftware.com/embedding-route-me-with-xcode-4-x/

Building the sample apps is pretty trivial.   If you're having issues with xcode and ios programming, might I suggest the very excellent series of courses (free!) from Stanford University available on apple itunes here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774

Ciao!